# How is $nq-1 = \sum_{m=0}^n (m-1){n \choose m} p^{n-m}q^m$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

$$nq-1 = \sum_{m=0}^n (m-1){n \choose m} p^{n-m}q^m$$
I found this formula in my facility planning book. The math part of it I don't understand.
I tried taking it apart like this $\sum_{m=0}^n (m){n \choose m}p^{n-m}q^m-\sum_{m=0}^n {n \choose m}*p^{n-m}q^m$ and calculate each term of the summation and it doesn't work.
Btw we have $\ p+q=1$.

I appreciate it if anyone can help me.

Comment: yes indeed sorry i forgot to add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=0}^n(m-1)\binom{n}mp^{n-m}q^m&=\sum_{m=0}^nm\binom{n}mp^{n-m}q^m-\sum_{m=0}^n\binom{n}mp^{n-m}q^m\\
&\overset{*}=\sum_{m=0}^nn\binom{n-1}{m-1}p^{n-m}q^m-(p+q)^n\\
&=n\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}mp^{n-(m+1)}q^{m+1}-1\\
&=nq\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}mp^{(n-1)-m}q^m-1\\
&\overset{*}=nq(p+q)^{n-1}-1\\
&=nq-1
\end{align*}$$

The starred steps use the binomial theorem.

Comment: You have an error in line 3 that leads to $p$ instead of $q$ in the final expression.

Comment: @RobPratt: Fixed; thanks!

Comment: Why you closed my question while it's not duplicate???

Answer (score 0):

Let $X \sim \text{Bin}(n,q)$. Then:
$$
\mathrm{E}[X] = \sum_{m=0}^n m{n \choose m}q^mp^{n-m}
$$
Binomial theorem asserts that:
$$
\sum_{m=0}^n {n \choose m}q^mp^{n-m} = (p + q)^n = 1
$$
We know that for a binomial random variable, $\mathrm{E}[X] = nq$. Therefore:
$$
\sum_{m=0}^n (m-1){n \choose m}q^mp^{n-m} = \sum_{m=0}^n m{n \choose m}q^mp^{n-m} - \sum_{m=0}^n {n \choose m}q^mp^{n-m} = \mathrm{E}[X] - 1 = nq-1
$$

Answer (score 0):

The second sum is $1$ by the binomial theorem.  For the first sum, note that
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=0}^n m{n \choose m}p^{n-m}q^m
&=\sum_{m=1}^n m{n \choose m}p^{n-m}q^m\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^n n{n-1 \choose m-1}p^{n-m}q^m\\
&=n q\sum_{m=1}^n {n-1 \choose m-1}p^{n-m}q^{m-1}\\
&=n q\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} {n-1 \choose m}p^{n-1-m}q^m\\
&=n q (p+q)^{n-1}\\
&=n q
\end{align}